# db interface similar to django model for use with Cherrypy

Tags: database, django, cherrypy

I would like to use a db interface library similar to django.model but with CherryPy.

I can use the django one, but given that I don't *have* to use the djanog.model, is there a better choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want SQLAlchemy.

You might want to look into Turbogears or Pylons/Pyramid as full-stack alternatives to Django.